# Can you select and join in one mysql query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Is it possible to SELECT a column from a row in mysql and then update some other column in that row without doing two queries? As of now, I am selecting from a table and then updating a column from the same row I selected with two separate queries

Comment: Can you show the queries that you are currently using?

Comment: IF you can provide the table structure & the queries, then only we can make a decision

Comment: You can write a stored procedure to do that. 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/stored-routines.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure about mysql but sql server allows you to use update 'table' set 'asignation'[,'asignation'] from 'select statment>' just like this

`UPDATE
    vendors ven1
SET
    ven1.parent_name = ven2.vendor_name
FROM`

```
vendors ven2
```

where 
    ven1.parent_id = ven2.ID

Answer (score 0):

Principally, if the SQL statement starts with "UPDATE ..." it may modify data, but doesn't return any record set. And if it starts with "SELECT ..." it returns records but does not have modifying side effects. This is even true with sub-queries as you cannot use UPDATE in a subquery.

All this also has to do with a structured separationof access rights (e.g. a user with only SELECT right should not be able to modify data).